# Deselect combobox text on leaving using suggestappend

Tags: vb.net

I have a databound ListItems combobox with AutoComplete.SuggestAppend 
and would like to navigate out of the combobox to different controls using the up/down arrow keys rather than scrolling the items.

The issue is that if the text isn't completed the suggested text remains highlighted while the next control has focus.

[Link to image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0lPN.jpg)

Here is some code showing a simple example of what I am doing

```
Public Class Form1
Dim PreventCboBoxChanging As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New List(Of String)(New String() {10, 11, 20, 30})
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
    If PreventCboBoxChanging = True Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    PreventCboBoxChanging = False
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        PreventCboBoxChanging = True
        TextBox1.Select()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        ComboBox1.Select()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validating
    Dim index As Integer = sender.FindString(sender.Text)
    If index > -1 Then
        sender.SelectedIndex = index
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Text = ""
        Beep()
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Is there any way to deselect the text?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another thread. Needed to turn off the Combobox AutoComplete Mode, change focus then reenable SuggestAppend mode under the PreviewKeyDown event.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
        TextBox1.Select()
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make it:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
    ComboBox1.SelectionLength = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Strangely it doesn't work.    I'm new here and don't know how to reply properly or post code.     ComboBox1_Leave >>
        ComboBox1.Text = ""  doesn't doesn't clear the textbox either.

Comment: @sgrya1, I don't know it it will help, but make sure you don't have duplicated, overlapping controls in your Form. It may accidentaly happen when copying controls with ^C^V... It happened to me once and it was a big pain until I noticed, because the control whose events I handled was hidden behind an exact copy of the control, so I was dealing with a diferent control than the one whose events I wanted to handle.