# Odd behaviour when trying to de-selecting text in Combobox with SuggestAppend

Tags: vb.net

I've got a DropDown combobox which is bound to a list. I am using SuggestAppend autocomplete based on the items from that list.

Once the item is selected from the suggest popup, the text is completed in the combobox as expected. However, the text stays selected and I am struggling to deselect it with an event. I can see a similar post ([Deselect combobox text on leaving using suggestappend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106963/deselect-combobox-text-on-leaving-using-suggestappend)) , however the solution doesn't seem to apply in my case.

My combobox code:

```
Private Sub CboIFAfirm_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CboIFAfirm.SelectedIndexChanged

If CboIFAfirm.SelectedIndex > -1 Then

    CboAdviser.SelectedIndex = -1

    With CboIFAfirm
    
        .SelectionStart = 0
        .SelectionLength = 0
    
    End With

    CboAdviser.Select()

End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried setting the autocomplete mode to None before selecting the next Combobox without luck.

Interestingly, when text is selected the selectionlength shows 0 so it sorts of doesn't see it...

**EDIT**:

Another approach has failed too - I have added SendKeys.Send("{End}") at the bottom of my SelectedIndexChanged event but it only seems to work without selecting CboAdviser!?

Comment: Have you tried doing `CboAdviser.Select(0, 0)` in the `SelectedTextChanged` event?

Comment: Just for clarity, I need the text in the CboIFAfirm deselected. I have just tried it in CBOIFAfirm but I can't use it as the TextChanged event (There is no SelectedTextChanged) fires on every keystroke and with the combo having autocomplete, it makes it unusable as when I start typing, some of the typed-in values are removed. I have also tested with SelectedValueChanged

Comment: Just `BeginInvoke(new Action(Sub() CboIFAfirm.SelectionLength = 0))` before `CboAdviser.Focus()`. Remove the `With` block.

Comment: That's done the trick @Jimi! Any idea why it has be done this way?

Comment: Because you're messing with the Controls Focus change events. `BeginInvoke()` (you can consider it as a *delayed operation*) causes that code to take affect only after the Focus has already been switched to a different Control and a new selection has already been created.